# Cntrl S to submit a from in react JS but input field not working

Tags: reactjs, forms, keyboard

// When i try to sumbit a from by ctrl s it submit but problem is input field not work
// when i comment onKeyDown input filed work but that's time i can't submit form using ctrl S

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("");
    const [contentEdit, setContentEdit] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = e => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
        console.log(e.target.value);
        setContentEdit(false);
    };


    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("you have searched for - " + value);
        // or you can send to backend
        setValue("");
    };

    const handleKeypress = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let charCode = String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();
        if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && charCode === 's') {
            console.log("CTRL+S Pressed");
            alert("CTRL+S Pressed");
            // onSubmitMemo();
            handleSubmit();
        }
    };

 <div
            onKeyDown={handleKeypress}
            contentEditable={true}
            className='border border-3 border-info'>
            <h1>Hello Ctrl + S to Submit</h1>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="email"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <input type="text" name="name"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code without the Ctrl + S it's working fine. But if you insert the `contentEditable={true}` props to `div` it doesn't work. But i have implemented for you. you can refer this.

```
import React from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");

  console.log(value, name);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    alert("you have searched for - " + value);
    // or you can send to backend
    setValue("");
    setName("");
  };

  const handleKeypress = (event) => {
    let charCode = String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();
    if (event.ctrlKey && charCode === "s") {
      console.log("CTRL+S Pressed");
      alert("CTRL+S Pressed");
      // onSubmitMemo();
      handleSubmit();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeypress(e)}
      className="border border-3 border-info"
    >
      <h1>Hello Ctrl + S to Submit</h1>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="email"
            onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
            value={value}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            value={name}
          />
          <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
            +
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It worked but now the problem is when using Ctrl + s handle submit function work also it shows default windows save popup after the function call. 
Hope so I explain well for your understanding :) 
Thank you

Comment: I think you're trying to say is that you're getting ```CTRL+S Pressed``` alert. Which is can be resolved if you remove alert from the function. if anything else let me know.

Comment: Now it's working --------
------
    const handleKeypress = (event) => {
        // event.preventDefault();
        let charCode = String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();
        if (event.ctrlKey && charCode === "s") {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("CTRL+S Pressed");
            // alert("CTRL+S Pressed");
            onSubmitMemo();
            // handleSubmit();

        }
    };

Comment: that's what i'm saying. :)

Comment: Thank you so much Vaiya
wish you a good future and health